# How to create customized UICollectionView with 2 or more custom cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, collectionview

in my project I want to use `UICollectionView` with custom cells, I created collection view with custom cells but I want to use Different size of custom cell in my project I followed some tutorials but I din`t get it properly, and below I attached sample screen shot of what i really looking for collection view.
[image: Example image] [image]

Comment: Attached Images are current implementation or desired ?

Comment: look same as the screen shots 
@Hemant

Comment: https://github.com/cp-satish-v/MosaicLayoutDemo

Answer (score 7):

One of the possible ways to create this is to use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` and then return the size for your `Cell`. Here are some useful links on Github which are exactly doing what you want :

1. [RF Quilt Layout](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout)
2. [Mosaic Layout](https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout)

As in the First image, some cells have buttons whereas others don't have. For this, you will have to create custom Cells i.e one custom cell with buttons and one without buttons. And inside your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function, you can define them with some `if-else` condition.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(firstCellConditionMet)
    {
        CustomCell1 *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //Your code

        return cell;
    }
    else{
        CustomCell2 *cell2 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

         //Your Code

         return cell2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Munahil   i will try :)

Comment: check the first screen shot ,  They added individual  buttons and how can i added these thing in collectionview

Comment: I think this will suffice the requirement.

Comment: still I'm confusing how to apply RF Quilt Layout or Mosaic Layout or waterfall layout with custom cells ?

Comment: What is your confusion?

Comment: i am not using any xib or Story board everything programatically , only thing custom cells xib. i created two different custom cells in one collection view when ever i scroll collection view i want to show two cells in view... LIKE same As eyeem App, I'm  not get it exactly the way to proceed.. Thanks

Comment: Your custom cells are programatically created or are XIBs? 
If they are XIBs, you will have to register them in ViewDidLoad or anywhere else like this : 
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell1" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

Comment: Is it showing some error? If not then what is it showing in its view?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by Collection View Flow Layout. You can create a flow layout and that layout will take care of different rows and how many elements are there in a row. Have a look at Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78551/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-2).

Answer (score 1):

if it is what you want

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFBTbmvFR30

try to use custom layout for collection view

https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

this is ready decision and it it is easy to use, If there are questions, will answer you,now i do the very similar collection...but on iPad with random cell size>>>>

[image]

and the most cool, with this realization you will be able to use one class for all cell sizes, if you use constraints. If you have problem with this realization, i can give you my test project.
Good luck bro.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very easy. You can subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Comment: Can you explain further how to do this?  Also generally SO encourages clear grammar because there are a lot of non-native English speakers on here and it is easier for them to understand if we all speak as clearly as possible.  Also just because it makes the site easier to understand and thus more useful.

Comment: Can you Explain me please @sixleaves