# Small And Big Cell Size with Sequence in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I would like to have 3 small cell, then 2 big cells, and then 3 small cells again, repeatedly, in my UICollectionView,

I know that it has something to do with this function, but I am confused as how to achieve the result

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

}
```

Please take a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create customized UICollectionView with 2 or more custom cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731675/how-to-create-customized-uicollectionview-with-2-or-more-custom-cells)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate modulo of `indexPath.row` like this way.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     if (indexPath.row % 5 == 3 || indexPath.row % 5 == 4) {
         //return big cell size
         let size = (collectionView.frame.size.width - minSpace) / 2
         return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
     }
     else {
         //return small cell size
         let size = (collectionView.frame.size.width - minSpace) / 3
         return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
     }
}
```

**Note:** Here **minSpace** is minimum space that you want between two cells.

Comment: Could you answer this question too, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221323/using-custom-layout-causes-collectionviewflowlayout-delegate-function-not-being

Comment: Let me check, if I have solution I will post it