# Using Custom Layout Causes collectionViewFlowLayout delegate function not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using [TRMosaicLayout](https://github.com/vinnyoodles/TRMosaicLayout) to achieve a SnapChat like layout.

However, after using it, I noticed that `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` is no longer called. Any thoughts?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    print("THIS FUNCTION IS NO LONGER CALLED");
    var view: UICollectionReusableView! = UICollectionReusableView();
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:

        loadingFooterView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "loadingFooterIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! LoadingFooterCollectionReusableView;

        view = loadingFooterView;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Are all other delegates working perfectly?

Comment: Basically all UICollectionFlowLayoutDelegates are no loger working. @arunjos007

Comment: Please check the following,
1) sets Datasource and Delegates correctly.
2) Make sure in `Attribute Inspector` the `Layout` option is `custom`

Comment: It looks like  TRMosaicLayout  doesn't support Supplementary View

Comment: @JayVDiyk I have downloaded the `TRMosaicLayout` layout and make a demo of it, I think @EvgeniyGushchin is right that this library doesn't support Supplementary view

Comment: @NiravD Thanks a lot for checking it out. If we were to add the header/footer view. How should we go about it? Any ideas?

Comment: @JayVDiyk Obviously I should go with Supplementary view but the problem is this lib is not supporting it, so it is hard to say what other solution to go with

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it @NiravD !

Comment: @JayVDiyk you can modify `TRMosaicLayout ` Just add necessary calculations for supplementary views

Comment: @EvgeniyGushchin Could you elaborate it please? Or better yet, an answer to this question? :D

Comment: @JayVDiyk this two tutorials will help you [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) and [Objc-io](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/)